# Need help understanding the difference in creating a Vue instance, which is best practice, and when would each option be used?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to wrap my head around which is the preferred and best practice method for creating your vue instance in your main.js. Creating a new project from the cli it creates the instace as such:

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

However, in the documentation here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Vue depicts creating your instance similar to this approach. You can add your el attribute if you want inside the new instance or mount it like I am below. Result seems to be the same, but I am looking for what is considered the best practice among the community, why is one better or recommended over the other, and any other information would be helpful.

```
const vm = new Vue({
  data: data,
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});

// Mount vue
vm.$mount("#app");
```

Thank you guys in advance!

I've read thru the documentation on Vue, searched and read thru articles and posts and haven't found a clear answer to distinguish which is best practice or when to use each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue instance can be associated with and manipulate an element which already exists, also you can have multiple Vue [instances](https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/using-multiple-vue-instances-page) in the same project, it's ok, however, you probably don't want to do that.

Vue component is more suitable for creating a new element and reuse it anywhere.

Comment: So between the two, which is considered the way you generally implement it? The first option or second option?

Comment: I prefer second option

Comment: Ok that's what I was leaning towards myself. It seems very flexible.